# What is the difference between GWT's Widget and UIObject

Tags: java, gwt

The doc says:

> The superclass for all user-interface objects. It simply wraps a
>   DOM element,  and cannot receive events. Most interesting
>   user-interface classes derive  from Widget

So why use a UIObject istead of Widgets? Are there performance costs etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at what extends [UIObject](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/UIObject.html) directly you'll see it's things like: menu items, tree items, menu item separator. Basically, it's things that are minor components of other widgets, and don't need rich functionality attached to them. It's generally a good design practice to use the smallest interface possible. If you don't need the functionality of a Widget then extend from UIObject.

In terms of performance costs, there's no difference - in GWT you (almost entirely) only "pay" (in terms of performance / download size) for what you use. It has an excellent compiler.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but the subject is still too vague for me. What's the "edge" moment one decides that he needs a Widget and not a UiObject any more?

Comment: Do you need it to receive events? Do you need to be able to add it to a panel? Then use Widget. If not, and all you need is to be able to style the element then use UIObject. In the vast majority of cases you'll want to use a Widget.

Answer (score 1):

widget is something we can make receive events and attach listeners to. but uiobject is something we can only show and style